# Formulas not updating if the other work book is closed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below formula which makes reference to another workbook in the same folder but when the file is open it just works fine, the problem is when the other excel file is closed because the formula wont get updated

Formula when the other workbook is open

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(Auto_Zero.xlsx!MonthDB,B6,Auto_Zero.xlsx!CSRDB,C2),"")
```

Formula when the other file is closed

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS('C:\Users\csamayoa\Desktop\QA 
Test\Auto_Zero.xlsx'!MonthDB,B6,'C:\Users\csamayoa\Desktop\QA 
Test\Auto_Zero.xlsx'!CSRDB,C2),"")
```

I have tried a lot of different suggestions and the formula does not wok when the other file is closed :(

Comment: If you create the formula with the external workbook open and then close it, Excel should provide the correct syntax.

Comment: I've tried that and when I close the other workbook and press F2 and enter to make sure it will work it does not.  I don't know what else I have to do

Comment: In any case, there are problems with countifs and closed workbooks. Use IF formulas with array setup:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel Functions like COUNTIFS and SUMIFS does not recalculate when referenced to closed workbook. You could try using Excel Query Designer which work like ADO codes. Allows retrieval from closed books, db etc.
Hope this helps.

the simplest way to achieve this without using advanced tools will be to use the code below to open the file, do the calculation and close the file back. Not sure if this help. Please change the 'H:\My Documents\4674576.xlsx' to your source file path. Paste this code in new module of your excel workbook. run the code and see if this helps.

`Sub loadfileandCalc()
Dim acWb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\My Documents\4674576.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set acWb = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Set acWb = Nothing
    wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing`

End Sub

Comment: I do not have any idea how to use Excel Query Designer and most of the formulas I will use are countif :(

Comment: Thanks Man , you're awsome . I left the formula : =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(Table1[CSR Name]),"",COUNTIFS('C:\Users\csamayoa\Desktop\QA Test\Auto_Zero.xlsx'!MonthDB,$B$6,'C:\Users\csamayoa\Desktop\QA Test\Auto_Zero.xlsx'!CSRDB,Table1[CSR Name])),"")                                .                                                                                                                  .                                                                                                                    I copied your vba code and changed the path . I added a button linked with the macro :)

Comment: I dont mind to click on a button as long as I get the information :D

Answer (score 2):

**Replacement Formulas for Formulas Linked to Closed Workbooks:**

Formulas such as `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF`, `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS`when linked to closed workbooks do not update their results.

The list below presents the replacement formulas that work with links to closed workbooks. It shows the syntax of the actual formula and its replacement in order to ease translation.

```
=COUNTIF( range, criteria )
=SUM(( range = criteria ) * 1 ) '*Entered as Formula Array*

=SUMIF( range, criteria, sum_range )
=SUMPRODUCT(( range = criteria ) * 1, sum_range )   

=COUNTIFS( criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2], [criteria2], ...)
=SUM(( criteria_range1 = criteria1 ) * ( [criteria_range2] = [criteria2] ), ...) '*Entered as Formula Array*

=SUMIFS( sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2], [criteria2], ...)
=SUMPRODUCT( sum_range, (criteria_range1 = criteria1 ) * ([criteria_range2] = [criteria2]) * ...)
```

*Formulas Array are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

Answer (score 0):

So an simple formula would be something like:

`=SUM((Auto_Zero.xlsx!MonthDB=B6)*(Auto_Zero.xlsx!CSRDB=C2))`

Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter the formula. Curly brackets should appear magically in the formula bar when this key-combination is used.

Comment: Thank you , MacroMarc . it works but when I close the other file I get #VALUE

Comment: The formula is missing enclosing parenthesis it should be `=SUM((Auto_Zero.xlsx!MonthDB=$B3)*(Auto_Zero.xlsx!CSRDB=$C3))`