# SUMIF to an external workbook gives #VALUE when the external workbook is closed. SUMPRODUCT gives a zero result

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I have created a `SUMIF` statement to an external workbook, to add up all the records in a range which are greater than 25. However, I get `#VALUE` when the external workbook is closed. From reading previous threads, I should be able to modify the `SUMIF` formula to a `SUMPRODUCT` to make it calculate with the external workbook closed, however, I get a zero result in my case.

The `SUMIF` formula, which works when the external workbook is open is:

```
=SUMIF('R:\Inbound Raw Materials\Gatehouse Folder\WeighBridge Weights\2019\March\[12.03.2019.xlsm]Sand'!$J$29:$J$53,">25")
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` alternative I have tried is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('R:\Inbound Raw Materials\Gatehouse Folder\WeighBridge Weights\2019\March\[12.03.2019.xlsm]Sand'!$J$29:$J$53 = ">25")*1)
```

Any advise which could be offered would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify, if you have both workbooks open then close the one, the formula changes from having a value to not having a value?

Comment: Hi Mistella, Not immediately. The correct value will remain immediately after the linked workbook is closed, but, next time I open the workbook with the formula, the result in #VALUE. So, the formula does not compute unless the linked workbook is open (with the SUMIF statement, that is.)

Comment: Have you tried saving the workbook with formulas while the formulas' are working and the linked workbook is closed?

Comment: Yes - Same result.

Comment: The issue is that SUMIF does not update when linked to a closed workbook. The following question, on this site, came up with a solution using SUMPRODUCT, but in this case it does not seem to work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874936/formulas-not-updating-if-the-other-work-book-is-closed/39903738#39903738

Comment: I have found the solution, Just a Syntax issue in the SUMPRODUCT function:

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7>25)*1,A1:A7)